# Convert HTML to PDF with links

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, html-to-pdf

Is there a node.js module or a javascript library that can convert HTML/Page into PDF with selectable texts and working links? I've tried Phantomjs. But since its the only screenshot the page and convert it to pdf, texts are not selectable and links are not working. Also tried jsPDF but links are not working either. Hope you guys can share some of your experience in dealing the same problem.

Your response is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can parse the HTML body with [htmlparser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/htmlparser). The complete html will be properly converted to JSON.

Depending upon the keys, you can then write it to a PDF using [pdfkit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfkit).

This is very general solution. If you give us an insight as to what type of HTML you want to get into a PDF, maybe then we would be able to help with some specific code or logic.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://www.cloudformatter.com/css2pdf.

Their links demo at http://www.cloudformatter.com/CSS2Pdf.Demos.Hyperlinks shows external links and internal links within the generated PDF.