# links to pages in pdf file converted from html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pdf, pdf-generation

In the `node.js` app i am making, writers can write articles using admin panel and integration with `tinyMCE` editor. Then it's needed to have possibility of downloading article as `pdf` file. I implemented it using [html-pdf](https://github.com/marcbachmann/node-html-pdf) package. In general its working fine, except internal links to pages. I tried to make it using this approach:

```
<a href="#page=4">go to page 4</a>
```

this works but only if pdf is opened in browser, if you open it with for example OS system "Viewer" it doesn't. I am getting message `There is no application set to open the URL test.pdf#?page=4`. I can imagine that if you make `pdf` document using something like `Adobe Acrobat Pro` it can be done easy. But can it be done when you are converting `html` to `pdf` using one of the packages for `node.js`?

I already checked different stack topics like this one: [Convert HTML to PDF with links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32109711/convert-html-to-pdf-with-links) which leads to this software [css2pdf](http://www.cloudformatter.com/css2pdf). When you check the demo in browser its working while as standalone `pdf` file - it doesn't. Maybe someone knows how to deal with it?

Comment: The message says `test.pdf#?page=4` so did you set the href to `#?page=4` or to `#page=4`? Because that could make a difference. The first one might be considered an external link, while the second an internal one.

Comment: i already tried all possible options `_file_name_.pdf#?page=4`, `_file_name_.pdf?#page=4`, `#?page=4`, `?#page=4`, `?page=4`, `#page=4`, the bottom line is, its' an url approach, and viewer does not support url's, so it must be done differently i suppose

Comment: Seems it's just not supported, but there might be workarounds: https://github.com/marcbachmann/node-html-pdf/issues/286

Comment: what you showed says there is workaround but link to this workaround is not clickable anymore (due to google plus changes)

Comment: @Mevia any update on this?

Comment: @Mevia I'm not sure if you still need this, but the css2pdf actually works for standalone PDF. The problem is, after the PDF is downloaded, the position of the links are shifted to the right for a few pixels. So, the clicking is not actually on the anchors